# How to execute more then one query in a prepared statement?

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, prepared-statement

I executed a query using prepared statement, now I wanna execute another query in the while loop. But It gives me an error that `Commands out of sync; you can't run this command now`. How to solve this issue?

```
<?php
$query = "SELECT post_id, post_title, post_author, post_date, post_image, post_content, post_tags FROM posts WHERE post_status = ? LIMIT ?, ?";
$stmt = mysqli_prepare($connection, $query);
if (!$stmt) {
  echo "Mysql error";
} else {
  mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "sii", $db_post_status, $page_1, $per_page);

  $db_post_status = "Published";

  mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
  mysqli_stmt_bind_result($stmt, $post_id, $post_title, $post_author, $post_date, $post_image, $post_content, $post_tags);
}                  

while (mysqli_stmt_fetch($stmt)) {

?>

   //// Some HTML code ////
   
<?php
  $query = "SELECT like_count FROM likes WHERE like_post_id = $post_id ";
  $sendQuery = mysqli_query($connection, $query);
  $likes = mysqli_num_rows($sendQuery);
?>
   
  //// Some HTML code ////
   
<?php } mysqli_stmt_close($stmt); ?>
```

Comment: Which line of your code fails?

Comment: @PaulSpiegel, My second query is not executing?

Comment: See: [Buffered and Unbuffered queries](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.concepts.buffering.php). But I think you can get the same with a single query. What is `$post_id` in the second query?

Comment: @PaulSpiegel `$post_id` is fetching from the first query, and It can't be static, so I need to execute the second query in the first query. But how can I enable buffering in prepared statement?

Answer (score 0):

PHP (mysqli) is using buffered queries by default. That means that rows are fetched one by one from the MySQL server. You can't execute any other query until the last row is fetched or the result is freed explicitly. Read the [documentation](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.concepts.buffering.php) if you want to use unbuffered queries. But I would rather fetch all rows at once with [`fetch_all()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-all.php), and then loop over the fetched rows with `foreach`. Or even better use a single query with your second query as correlated subquery:

```
$query = "
    SELECT
      post_id,
      post_title,
      post_author,
      post_date,
      post_image,
      post_content,
      post_tags,
      (SELECT like_count FROM likes WHERE like_post_id = post.post_id) as like_count
    FROM posts
    WHERE post_status = ?
    LIMIT ?, ?
";
```

Then include `$like_count` in `bind_result()`:

```
mysqli_stmt_bind_result($stmt, $post_id, ... , $post_tags, $like_count);
```